# Unable to load library 'libtesseract302' in Play project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dll, playframework-2.0, tesseract

I'm trying to use tess4j in a play project. I have put **tess4j.jar, libtesseract302.dll and liblept168.dll** in play project lib folder and setting java.library.path and jna.library.path when starting play server like this:
`play -Djava.library.path=lib -Djna.library.path=lib start`

Note that **i have used 64-bit dlls which have been released here**: https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/tree/master/src/lib/TesseractOcr/x64. This link has been stated in Tess4j official website as well.

But still, i'm getting " Unable to load library 'libtesseract302'" exception. I tried to set the absolute path of lib folder too, nothing works.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For using Tess4j try putting the **libtesseract302.dll** in the **Project Folder** and not in the **lib** Folder.
That is how it worked in my project.

But The error can be a result from various situations other than the location of .dll file

This problem may arise when -

1. You are trying run Tess4j on a 64 bit JVM instead of 32 bit, it gives the same error inspite of placing the .dll files into the perfect location
2. You do not have Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable installed (Specifically 2008) 
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29

After fixing all these it should work

Comment: Those DLLs were built with VS2013 and therefore depend on the [Visual C++ Runtime for VS2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40784).

Comment: Or it could be [Visual C++ Redistributable for VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

Comment: Thanks Jay. But i'm using 64-bit dlls downloaded from the location i have mentioned in my question. I installed Visual C++ from the link nguyenq has shared (VS2013) and placed these dlls in play project folder, but still this issue persists.

Comment: if we included the correct 64 bit .DLL's do we still need the Visual C++ Runtime? And if so, how do you get the Visual C++ Runtime onto a linux app server?

Answer (score 0):

Put the JAR in the `classpath`. `java.library.path` is for the native libraries (.dll, .so, .dylib).

Comment: Jar is already in the classpath. I have put the dlls in the same folder and given java.library.path as the same.